# Replace last two letters in Java

Tags: java, string, methods

I am asking for help on this code that I am making, I want it to replace the last two letters. I am coding a program that will:

1. Replace four letter words with "FRED"
2. Replace the last two letters of a word that ends with "ed" to "id"
3. Finally, replace the first two letters if the word starts with "di" to "id"

I am having difficulty with the second stated rule, I know that for number 3 I can just use `replaceFirst()` and to use the length for the first rule, but I am not sure how to specifically swap the last two characters in the string.

Here is what I have so far:

```java
package KingFred;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KingFredofId2 {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String king = input.nextLine();
    String king22 = new String();
    String king23 = new String();
    if(king.length()==4)
    {
        System.out.println("FRED");
    }
    String myString = king.substring(Math.max(king.length() - 2, 0));
    if (myString.equals("ed")) 
    {
        king22 = king.replace("ed", "id");
        System.out.println(king22);
    }
    if(true)
    {
        king23 = king.replace("di", "id");
        System.out.println(king23);
    }
}
```

I am new to Stack Overflow, so please let me know how I can make my questions a little more understandable if this one is not easily comprehended.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you didn't understand the requirements of your task. "Replace four letter words with FRED" doesn't mean "If your input is 4 letters long print FRED". It means, if your input is something like "My cat went to West Virginia", you need to produce the string "My cat FRED to FRED Virginia".

Comment: @RealSkeptic You are correct, that is my mistake, I will fix that immediately.

Comment: Are you expecting one word per line in the input?  Or can each line of input contain multiple words?

Comment: @VGR I am supposed to first do one word per line input, once that is completed, I must modify it so that the input can contain multiple words.  I am doing my research as to how to properly complete the first rule.

Comment: If you use regexes you can that with two lines of code

Comment: @g00se I had the same thought, but regular expressions might be ahead of where Ali is in the learning process right now.

Comment: Yes. Also amusing to note that any four-letter word would be turned into "FRID" (?) ;)

Comment: @g00se, "FRED" is not necessarily the same as "Fred".

Comment: Hehe - true. I was forgetting case

Comment: Given the word `died`, what is the result?  Basically, what is the priority for changing the words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a way to more optimally combine the regular expressions, but this will work.

- `\\b` - word boundary (white space, punctuation,etc).
- `\\b(?:\\w){4}\\b` - four letter word
- `ed\\b` - word ending with `ed`
- `\\bdi`  - word starting with `di`
- `replaceAll(regex,b)` - replace what `regex` matches with string `b`

```
String s =
        "Bill charles among hello fool march good deed, dirt, dirty, divine dried freed died";
s = s.replaceAll("\\b(?:\\w){4}\\b", "FRED")
        .replaceAll("ed\\b", "id")
        .replaceAll("\\bdi", "id");

System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
FRED charles among hello FRED march FRED FRED, FRED, idrty, idvine driid freid F
RED
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simplest way I could think to solve the second case of replacing the last two characters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a line or a word: ");
        String s = sc.nextLine();

        //getting the length of entered string
        int length = s.length();
        
        //initializing a new string to hold the last two characters of the entered string
        String extract = "";

        //checking if length of entered string is more than 2
        if (length > 2) {
            //extracting the last two letters
            extract = s.substring(length - 2);
            //updating the original string
            s = s.substring(0, length - 2);
        }


        //checking if the last two characters fulfil the condition for changing them
        if (extract.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
            //if they do, concatenate "id" to the now updated original string
            System.out.println(s + "id");
        } else {
            //or print the originally entered string
            System.out.println(s + extract);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the comments are giving enough explanation and further explanation is not needed.